# OSX launchd - running script in the Background Session ignores StartInterval

Tags: php, macos, intervals, launchd

Community!

I am trying to execute a simple script every 5 minutes on my OSX 10.7.4. It should run no matter a user is logged into the machine or not (aka in the background session)

Thus I created I com.me.script.plist in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/`
and loaded it via: `launchctl -S background ./com.me.script.plist`
and started it via: `launchchctl start com.me.script`

It runs fine the first time. But it never runs again after my set interval of 300seconds!

Do you guys have any advice as to why that could be? If I run it in the Aqua Session it works perfectly, however, that means it'll only run if a user is logged in. However, I'd really need it to start running before that... and continue to do so no matter if a user logs in/out or another user logs in/out.

Here's my plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
        <string>Background</string>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.me.script</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/bin/php</string>
            <string>/Sites/script/notifier.php</string>
        </array>
        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>900</integer>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own mistake... StartInterval should be 300 and not 900 if I expect it to run every 5min. sorry, stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to say the issue lies here:

```
<string>/Sites/script/notifier.php</string>
```

Did you mean to write the following?

```
<string>/Users/username/Sites/script/notifier.php</string>
```

Starting your path with `/` implied the path starts at the root of the drive, which OSX has no `/Sites` directory on the root by default.

Comment: I added it into the root in order for every user to have access to it.. and I found my problem: StartInterval was set at 900 .. instead of 300. Sorry